# How to segment wooden tiles using image processing?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have a pallet of wooden tiles. The tiles can be both white or grey color. There are examples of the images:

[image: White tiles]

[image: Grey tiles].

I want to implement segmentation of the tiles area, so we don't see the cardboard part.

I have tried simple thresholding, Otsu thresholding, watershed algorithm. Could be that I am applying them wrong, but I can't manage to achieve segmenting only the area of wooden tiles. Any ideas I should try?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of segmenting an image. Its a vast field.

Here i think you have a lightining issue, the left part of the image is lighter than the right part, causing the cardboard from the left to be equal to some of tiles. Maybe other color channels may help you, such as HSV( or HSL) or LAB...

This may help you:

```py
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load the image
image = cv.imread('your_image')
# blur it
blurred = cv.GaussianBlur(image,(11,11),0)
hsv = cv.cvtColor(blurred, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)  # Convert to RGB format

#define lower and upper bounds.
grayLower = (30,   0, 130)  
grayUpper = (180,   80, 180)  
mask = cv.inRange(hsv, grayLower, grayUpper)
res = cv.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = mask)
plt.imshow(res)
plt.show()
```

[image: res]

The code comes from: [reference](https://pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/14/ball-tracking-with-opencv/)

The code creates a mask that looks inside the HSV channel for gray colors inside a boundary, then it recreates the image with that mask.

After that it may be easy to find the the biggest rectangle in the middle with other manipulations such as findCountour or morphology.